# Страничка на питон не работает, я продолжаю получать этот текст:

Tags: python, flask

Код app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

# Путь к папке, где будут храниться загруженные файлы
UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'uploads'
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

# Функция для загрузки файлов
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        if file:
            # Сохраняем файл в папку uploads на сервере
            filename = file.filename
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))

# Функция для удаления файлов
def delete_file(filename):
    file_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
    if os.path.exists(file_path):
        os.remove(file_path)

# Основная страница приложения
@app.route('/')
def index():
    # Список файлов в папке uploads
    files = os.listdir(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'])
    return render_template('index.html', files=files)

# Страница для загрузки файлов
@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        upload_file()
        return "Файл загружен"
    else:
        return render_template('upload.html')

# Страница для удаления файлов
@app.route('/delete', methods=['POST'])
def delete():
    filename = request.form.get('filename')
    if filename:
        delete_file(filename)
        return "Файл удален"
    else:
        return "Ошибка: не выбран файл для удаления"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=8080, debug=True) файл
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Загрузка файлов</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Список файлов:</h1>
    <ul>
      {% for filename in files %}
        <li>{{ filename }}</li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <form action="/delete" method="post">
      <label for="filename">Выберите файл для удаления:</label>
      <select id="filename" name="filename">
        {% for filename in files %}
          <option value="{{ filename }}">{{ filename }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
      </select>
      <button type="submit">Удалить</button>
    </form>
    <hr>
    <a href="/upload">Загрузить новый файл</a>
  </body>
</html> файл upload.html: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Загрузка файла</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Загрузка файла</h1>
    <form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="file">
      <button type="submit">Загрузить</button>
    </form>
    <hr>
    <a href="/">На главную</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

файл upload.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Загрузка файла</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Загрузка файла</h1>
    <form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="file">
      <button type="submit">Загрузить</button>
    </form>
    <hr>
    <a href="/">На главную</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Файлы app.py и upload.html, а также папки upload и templates назодятся в папке site. Папка uploads пуста, а в папке templates находится файл index.html, что делать, почему не работает? Заранее благодарен

Comment: Какой текст вы продолжаете получать?

Comment: Как вы сервер запускаете?